# Confirmation on how to check microcontroller memory capacity with Atmel Studio

Tags: microcontroller, atmel, atmel-studio

When compiling code in Atmel Studio, I get the following output showing the percentage of usage for the program and data memory:

[image]

Does this output represent the total data usage in the microcontroller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These figures will not include any memory used for the stack or any memory that you allocate dynamically at runtime. Also, if you have connected external memory devices to the microcontroller then the tools won't include that memory in the calculations.

Other than that, this should be your total memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

It will only include the memory allocated during compilation time, not the one added during runtime. If you want to validate the information during compilation time you can check the file .map which contain all information of memory used.

Here is an example of how the memory is mapped into the microcontroller:
**ADC_EXAMPLE11.map**

| Name | Origin | Length |
| --- | --- | --- |
| text | 0x00000000 | 0x00002000 |
| data | 0x00800060 | 0x0000ffa0 |
| eeprom | 0x00810000 | 0x00010000 |
| fuse | 0x00820000 | 0x00000003 |
| lock | 0x00830000 | 0x00000003 |
| signatures | 0x00840000 | 0x00000400 |
| user signatures | 0x00840000 | 0x00000400 |
| default | 0x00000000 | 0x00000400 |

It tells you the range in memory used by each section but below in that file you can find the real memory used:

| Name | Origin | Used |
| --- | --- | --- |
| .text | 0x00000000 | 0x72 |
| .data | 0x00800060 | 0x00 |
| .bss | 0x00800100 | 0x00 |
| .noinit | 0x00800100 | 0x00 |
| .eeprom | 0x00810000 | 0x00 |

Once known that, you just can calculate the percentage of flash used:

- Total flash = 0x00000000 + 0x00002000 = 0x00002000 = 8192 bytes
- Flash used = 0x00000000 + 0x78 = 0x00000078 = 120 bytes
- Percentage = (120 bytes * 100)/(8192 bytes) = 1.46%

Results reported by Atmel Studio
[image]